# Powershell not finding built in cmdlets

Tags: powershell

Powershell can't find the built in cmdlets when running one of my scripts:

My code:

```
# (Some code which I think is irrelevant but runs fine) Then...

# Load a third party assembly, which in turn loads other assemblies
# so I have to change the Powershell process' directory so that 
# the other assemblies are visible
[System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($ThirdPartyInstallPath)
Add-Type -Path "$ThirdPartyInstallPath\ThirdPatyAssembly.dll"

# (1) Deliberately commented out call to Get-Item - so it does nothing
# $myFileInfo = Get-Item -Path "C:\My Path\File I know exists.txt"

# (2) call to third party API
ThirdPartyFunction()    

# (3) Second call to Get-Item
# (*) This is the code that fails 
$myFileInfo = Get-Item -Path "C:\My Path\File I know exists.txt"
```

If I run this using powershell.exe (but not ISE, oddly) the error message is:

```
The term 'Get-Item' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.
At C:\Projects\Test Host\Test_Script.ps1:21 char:11
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Item:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

However, the script runs fine under the following circumstances:

- When I run the same script in Powershell ISE (by loading and pressing the green Run button), without changes, everything runs fine.
- Back to running in powershell.exe, if I uncomment out (1) hence include a call to Get-Item before the third party API call, it works fine
- Running in powershell.exe, if I comment out the third party API call (2) then it works fine [whether (1) is commented or uncommented]

I have checked that `$PSModulePath` and the system PATH are not changed during the third party API call, they are not changed and their values are as per Frode's comment below

I have tried to see what is happening "under the bonnet" by using Sysinternal's Process Monitor. This tells me that before the error, Powershell:

- First searches the path for `Get-Item.exe`, `Get-Item.ps1` etc but does not find anything
- Then looks in the `.psd1` files under the `$PSModulePath`, which includes `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`.
- It will find that the `Get-Item` cmdlet is exported by `Microsoft.Powershell.Management.psd1`
- It then reads from the `Microsoft.Powershell.Management.dll`

I see exactly the same behaviour when I make the changes set out above which eliminate the error. Therefore I do not think that it is a case of a setting being messed up by the third party DLL and causing Powershell to be unable to find the built in cmdlets.

I don't know if this is relevant, but: the third party assembly loads System.Management.Automation v1.0.0.0 which is compiled against .Net v2.0.50727. This is because the third party library is itself a Powershell host (although I do not use that feature of it in the code).

I've seen references to "constraints on the runspace" in other posts on the web, but have not seen this specific problem.

What is causing the problem? How to diagnose it? How to resolve it?

Comment: If there are any questions arising then I will update the post to reflect them

Comment: What does `$env:PSModulePath` return? It should looks something like `C:\Users\frode\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ ` unless something in your script or the module modifies it.

Comment: Yes it is saying a similar thing to yours. I've included more information in the question too